# Chart.js change the label for each data point on a chart

Tags: javascript, charts

I am using Chart.js and am struggling to figure out how to overwrite the defaults when the user hovers over a data point on the graph.  Currently when I hover the mouse over a data point the X and Y coordinates appear.  Is there a way to change what is displayed.

Here is the for loop I am using for to give each data point its value.

```
 for (var j = 0; j < sub_array_scores.length; j++) {
                var data = {
                    x: new Date(sub_array_dates[j]),
                    y: sub_array_scores[j],
                    r: 5
                };
                coordinates.push(data);
            }
```

and here is an image of what appears when I hover over a point in the graph
[image]
How would I change that to say instead your score is: Y

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a minimal example via JSFiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are custom Tooltips what you're looking for?

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html